Why is the usage of add and multiply different for multi-channel cv::Mat?
I want to perform element-by-element addition and multiplication on a multi-channel cv::Mat.
for add of multi-channel cv::Mat:
cv::Mat tmp = cv::Mat(cv::Size(5, 3), CV_32FC3, cv::Scalar(1, 1, 1));
tmp += 0.5;
std::cout << tmp << "\n";

The output is that only the first channel performs the addition:
[1.5, 1, 1, 1.5, 1, 1, 1.5, 1, 1, 1.5, 1, 1, 1.5, 1, 1;
 1.5, 1, 1, 1.5, 1, 1, 1.5, 1, 1, 1.5, 1, 1, 1.5, 1, 1;
 1.5, 1, 1, 1.5, 1, 1, 1.5, 1, 1, 1.5, 1, 1, 1.5, 1, 1]

note: the correct way is tmp += cv::Scalar(0.5, 0.5, 0.5);
for mul of multi-channel cv::Mat:
cv::Mat tmp = cv::Mat(cv::Size(5, 3), CV_32FC3, cv::Scalar(1, 1, 1));
tmp *= 2;
std::cout << tmp << "\n";

The output is that all channels performs the multiply:
[2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2;
 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2;
 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]

Why do I have to use cv::Scalar for addition, but can use a constant for multiplication?

Because of operator+ (const Mat &a, const Scalar &s) and operator* (const Mat &a, double s) have different semantics.

as to the "why": perhaps an oversight of whoever implemented it. There appears to be an overload that handles the multiplication by an integer/float, but no such case that handles the addition. (I did not verify this hypothesis!) Hence, the promotion of your 0.5 to a cv::Scalar(0.5) constructor, which fills the unspecified elements of the cv::Scalar with 0. -- I haven't posted this as an answer yet because I didn't verify it.
